# Tkinter, using pack: can't keep footer bar at bottom

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

I am trying to have a bottom row of three buttons evenly spaced, but because I am using `side="left"` and `side="right"` the other buttons end up in the middle.

Sample code:
    import tkinter as tki

```
class App(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tki.Tk()
        self.root.config(bg="white")
        self.root.geometry("400x300")


        top_frm = tki.Frame(self.root).pack()
        T = tki.Text(top_frm, height=2, width=30)
        T.pack()
        T.insert(tki.END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")

        mdl_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width="400").pack(fill="both",expand=True)

        lbut = tki.Button(mdl_frm, text='Left button').pack(side="left")
        rbut = tki.Button(mdl_frm, text='right button').pack(side="right")

        bottom_frm = tki.Frame(self.root).pack(side="bottom",fill="x",expand=False)

        btn_frm_r = tki.Frame(bottom_frm).pack(side="right",fill="x")
        btn_frm_c = tki.Frame(bottom_frm).pack(side="right",fill="x")
        btn_frm_l = tki.Frame(bottom_frm).pack(side="right",fill="x")
        button1 = tki.Button(btn_frm_r,text='Bottom button 1').pack()
        button2 = tki.Button(btn_frm_c,text='Bottom button 2').pack()
        button3 = tki.Button(btn_frm_l,text='Bottom button 3').pack()

app = App()
#launch the app
app.root.mainloop()
```

I have tried putting the "left button" and "right button" in a frame. 
I read somewhere that when using `side` declarations, when something is given a region it controls that region completely, so I tried declaring the `btm_frm` frame first and using `side="bottom"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.pack()` returns `None`, therefore you cannot `.pack()` and assign to a variable on one line.
Further, I'f recommend packing the frame once you have placed other objects into it.
Last, I'd recommend to use `self.` for your class attributes; you will find it useful when need to access them later.

```
import tkinter as tki

class App(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tki.Tk()
        self.root.config(bg="white")
        self.root.geometry("400x300")


        self.top_frm = tki.Frame(self.root)
        self.top_frm.pack()
        self.T = tki.Text(self.top_frm, height=2, width=30)
        self.T.pack()
        self.T.insert(tki.END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")

        self.mdl_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width="400")
        self.mdl_frm.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

        self.lbut = tki.Button(self.mdl_frm, text='Left button')
        self.lbut.pack(side="left")
        self.rbut = tki.Button(self.mdl_frm, text='right button')
        self.rbut.pack(side="right")

        self.bottom_frm = tki.Frame(self.root)

        self.btn_frm_r = tki.Frame(self.bottom_frm)
        self.btn_frm_r.pack(side="right",fill="x")
        self.btn_frm_c = tki.Frame(self.bottom_frm)
        self.btn_frm_c.pack(side="right",fill="x")
        self.btn_frm_l = tki.Frame(self.bottom_frm)
        self.btn_frm_l.pack(side="right",fill="x")
        self.button1 = tki.Button(self.btn_frm_r,text='Bottom button 1')
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = tki.Button(self.btn_frm_c,text='Bottom button 2')
        self.button2.pack()
        self.button3 = tki.Button(self.btn_frm_l,text='Bottom button 3')
        self.button3.pack()

        self.bottom_frm.pack(side="bottom",fill="x",expand=False)



app = App()
#launch the app
app.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `side='left'` or `side='right'` for your buttons since you want them to go left-to-right within their containing frame.

```
    button1 = tki.Button(btn_frm_r,text='Bottom button 1').pack(side="left")
    button2 = tki.Button(btn_frm_c,text='Bottom button 2').pack(side="left")
    button3 = tki.Button(btn_frm_l,text='Bottom button 3').pack(side="left")
```

By the way, if you're going to do `tki.Button(...).pack(...)`, there's no point in assigning it to a variable. The variable will always have the value `None`.

A full explanation of the `pack` algorithm is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26